# Python DataFrame and for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Python. Wanted to concatenate the contents of a, b and c using a `for` loop and `DataFrame` and store it in df.

```python
import pandas as pd
a=['ab_','cd_','ef_']
b=['xyz','pqr','hij']
c=['.txt']
print(a,b,c)

df = pd.DataFrame()
print(df)

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        for l in c:
                df=df.append(a[0]+b[0]+c[0])
print(df)
```

But getting this error. So please let me know what needs to be done here.

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: Please add an expect output to your post.

Comment: `[f"{i}{c[0]}" for i in map(''.join,zip(a,b))]` ? why do you need pandas though

Comment: Expected O/p: I want to take an empty dataframe then append the output to the df. ab_xyz.txt ab_pqr.txt ab_hij.txt like wise